# Puppet | Solution for XML edit

Tags: xml, puppet

i try use puppet, but my experience so low. I need your help ;)

I want edit XML file (libreoffice settings)

```
...
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Paths/Paths/org.openoffice.Office.Paths:NamedPath['Template']"><prop oor:name="UserPaths" oor:op="fuse"><value></value></prop></item>
...
```

i need add 1,2 user paths (, inside ). Final XML should be like this

```
...
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Paths/Paths/org.openoffice.Office.Paths:NamedPath['Template']"><prop oor:name="UserPaths" oor:op="fuse"><value><it>file:///path/to/dir1/</it><it>file:///path/to/dir2/</it></value></prop></item>
...
```

How i can make it with puppet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stdlib function file_line to replace the line in question.

the function can replace a line in your xml file with a new line with data you want.

**Example :**

```
file_line { 'Change file xml file line': 
ensure => present, 
path => '/xml/file/path', 
line => '<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Paths/Paths/org.openoffice.Office.Paths:NamedPath['Template']"><prop oor:name="UserPaths" oor:op="fuse"><value><it>file:///path/to/dir1/</it><it>file:///path/to/dir2/</it></value></prop></item>', 
match => '<item oor:path=', 
}
```

---

Please check for more info about the file_line function

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib